# How to set Margins for View in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I have a view in an activity as below .I want to set Margin to the view.But i used Viewgroup.LayoutParams but it doesn't change the view of the row.Below i have given custom adapter which takes data from firstpagerowitems.xml.I have given the java code for adapter .I tried doing android:layout_marginbottom="10dp" for firstpagerowitems.xml and firstpage.xml but it doesnt work.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<String> rTitle;
        ArrayList<String> rDescription;
        ArrayList<String> rImgs;

        MyAdapter (Context c, ArrayList<String> title,ArrayList<String> description,ArrayList<String> imgs) {
            super(c, R.layout.firstpagerowitems, R.id.textView1, title);
            this.context = c;
            this.rTitle = title;
            this.rDescription = description;
            this.rImgs = imgs;

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.firstpagerowitems, parent, false);
            TextView images = row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            TextView myTitle = row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView myDescription = row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Log.d("entered last","yes");
            Log.d("postion", String.valueOf(position));
            Log.d("rimgs", String.valueOf(rImgs));
            Log.d("desc", String.valueOf(rDescription));
            Log.d("title", String.valueOf(rTitle));

            // now set our resources on views
            images.setText(rImgs.get(position));
            myTitle.setText(rTitle.get(position));
            myDescription.setText(rDescription.get(position));
            Random random=new Random();
            int trp=random.nextInt(16);
            Log.d("enteredcolor",mycolors[trp]);
//            images.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightgreen);
            String fd=mycolors[trp];
//            images.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(fd));
//            LinearLayout mylinear=row.findViewById(R.id.mylinear);
//            mylinear.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(fd));
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(fd));
//            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margins=new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(row.getLayoutParams());
//            margins.setMargins(0,100,0,100);
//            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layouts=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(margins);
//            row.setLayoutParams(layouts);
//            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(row);




            return row;
        }
    }
```

code.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="two"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="three"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

firsypagerowitems.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".Firstpage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/mylinear">
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                >
            </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fabs"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_error"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        >
    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

firstpage.xml

Comment: Why are you giving the `layout_width` to `0dp`?

Comment: I want to give layout_weight percentage

Answer (score 1):

Try whether this helps...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="two"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="three"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: What kind of margin do you want to give? Horizontally between textviews or altogether to the whole layout?

Comment: I want to give margins between two rows @Vishnu

Comment: Why cannot i keep margin for linear layout?

Comment: @Rocky, Of course, You can. I just removed unnecessary code... Please mark this as the accepted answer(Green Tick Mark) and Upvote if this helped...